# Can't find where .sol files are stored in the local storage of the browser

Tags: remix

I lost all my workspaces in Remix (running on Brave). I opened the developer console to explore the indexeddb storage to try to find my files. But I found nothing. I tried to search in Local Storage of remix.ethereum.org but I didn't find the .sol there. Where I could try to find the .sol files?

Answer (score 0):

there was the same issue on Windows laptop.

I selected `File -> Open Folder` in the main menu, and then I connected to `localhost` as a worksapce.

> Remixd enables you to have access to a selected folder on your hard drive.

https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/file_explorer.html#file-storage-outside-of-the-browser-and-version-control